# i can´t start a new project in nuxt

Tags: node.js, npm, nuxt.js

i need to start a new Nuxt project but i can't

i cleared cache using `npm cache clean --force` ;

i deleted `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`

but the result is the same

this is the error in console

...

```
C:\laragon\www\estudio\auth-nuxt-nuevo\node_modules\@nuxt\utils\dist\utils.js:1752
      const match = asString.match(/^([^{(]+)=>\s*(.*)/s);
                                   ^

SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\laragon\www\estudio\auth-nuxt-nuevo\node_modules\@nuxt\cli\dist\cli-chunk.js:15:15)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! auth-nuxt-nuevo@1.0.0 dev: `nuxt`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the auth-nuxt-nuevo@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Edmundo Esquivel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-28T05_51_02_885Z-debug.log
```

...

this is the log

Comment: How did you try and create it?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in nuxt 2.6.3. it's happening only on node8, and it will be fixed in next minor release https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/5608

For now you can either downgrade nuxt version or update your node version to 10. I suggest to update node